# Operator ">" cannot be applied to type 'ulong' and 'int'

Tags: c#, .net

I'm curious to know why the C# compiler only gives me an error message for the second if statement.

```
enum Permissions : ulong
{
    ViewListItems = 1L,
}

public void Method()
{
    int mask = 138612833;
    int compare = 32;

    if (mask > 0 & (ulong)Permissions.ViewListItems > 32)
    {
        //Works
    }

    if (mask > 0 & (ulong)Permissions.ViewListItems > compare)
    {
        //Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ulong' and 'int'
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason for this error is clear.  In the second example you are trying to perform an illegal operation with an integer.  In the first example `32` is being treated as a `ulong`.  You should actually make `mask` a `ulong`.

Comment: @Ramhound Either that (make `compare` an `ulong`), or make `compare` a `const` variable, so `const int compare = 32;`. Constant expressions will happily convert automatically from `int` to `ulong` at compile-time if they are non-negative, something which goes under the name _Implicit constant expression conversions_.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I've been experimenting with this, using ILSpy to examine the output, and this is what I've discovered.

Obviously in your second case this is an error - you can't compare a `ulong` and an `int` because there isn't a type you can coerce both to. A `ulong` might be too big for a `long`, and an `int` might be negative.

In your first case, however, the compiler is being clever. It realises that const `1` > const `32` is never true, and doesn't include your `if` statement in the compiled output at all. (It should give a warning for unreachable code.) It's the same if you define and use a `const int` rather than a literal, or even if you cast the literal explicitly (i.e. `(int)32`).

But then isn't the *compiler* successfully comparing a `ulong` with an `int`, which we just said was impossible?

Apparently not. So what *is* going on?

Try instead to do something along the following lines. (Taking input and writing output so the compiler doesn't compile anything away.)

```
const int thirtytwo = 32;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ulong x = ulong.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    bool gt = x > thirtytwo;
    Console.WriteLine(gt);
}
```

This will compile, even though the `ulong` is a variable, and even though the result isn't known at compile time. Take a look at the output in ILSpy:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ulong x = ulong.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    bool gt = x > 32uL;        /* Oh look, a ulong. */
    Console.WriteLine(gt);
}
```

So, the compiler is in fact treating your `const int` as a `ulong`. If you make `thirtytwo = -1`, the code fails to compile, even though we then know that `gt` will *always* be true. The compiler itself can't compare a `ulong` to an `int`.

Also note that if you make `x` a `long` instead of a `ulong`, the compiler generates `32L` rather than `32` as an integer, even though it doesn't *have* to. (You can compare an `int` and a `long` at runtime.)

This points to the compiler not treating `32` as a `ulong` in the first case because it *has* to, merely because it *can* match the type of `x`. It's saving the runtime from having to coerce the constant, and this is just a bonus when the coercion should by rights not be possible.

Comment: This was a very interesting read, props to you for the research.

Comment: @Amicable - props to _you_ for an interesting question that made me want to research it :)

Comment: The C# compiler is entirely in agreement with the C# Language Specification here. When an expression of type `int` is a compile-time constant, there do exist an [implicit constant expression conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691286.aspx) from `int` to `ulong` _provided that the value is within the range_ of `ulong`, i.e. non-negative, which is something the C# compiler can see with a constant expression. `32` is a constant expression of type `int`. When an expression of type `int` is _not_ a compile-time constant, no implicit conversion exists to `ulong`. Example `compare`.

Comment: "because there isn't a type you can coerce both to" -- thank you!

Answer (score 21):

It's not the CLR giving this error message it's the compiler.

In your first example the compiler treats `32` as `ulong` (or a type that's implicitly convertible to `ulong` eg `uint`) whereas in your second example you've explicitly declared the type as an `int`. There is no overload of the `>` operator that accepts an `ulong` and an `int` and hence you get a compiler error.

Comment: The integer literals page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674.aspx) says "If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: int, uint, long, ulong." Plus my Intellisense (tooltip) says the `32` is an `int`. But this does seem to be what's happening...

Comment: @Rawling Very true, I can see three possible reasons (I daresay there are many more): #1 perhaps because of differing interpretations of "value can be represented", ie the compiler knows that 32 cannot be an int since the code would not compile and tries uint next which succeeds. Intellisense obviously doesn't evaluate the entire expression to calculate the type, int is generally correct so why sacrifice computing time for an edge case. #2 the documentation for integer literals is outdated. Or #3 it's a compiler bug.

Comment: @Rawling - There isn't a bug it is working exactly like it should. The literal `32` is being treated as a `long`.  You even quote the statement where it says it will be treated as a `long`.

Comment: @ramhound you can't compare a long either.

Comment: @Ramhound: It is not being treated as a `long`.  Read the rule again.

Comment: @rich Actually after further work with ILSpy, I can see that you're right. The compiler does actually treat `32`, which by my reading should be treated as an `int`, as a `ulong`. Whether or not it goes on to compile it out is a separate issue.

Answer (score 3):

rich.okelly and rawling's answers are correct as to why you cannot compare them directly. You can use the [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) class's [ToUInt64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78c1y5th.aspx) method to promote the int.

```
if (mask > 0 & (ulong)Permissions.ViewListItems > Convert.ToUInt64(compare))
{
}
```