# Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'long' and 'ulong'

Tags: c#, binary-operators, .net-reflector, ulong

I've used the .NET Reflector 8 by redgate and I used the feature that exports the .dll to C# files and I am running into one error situation that I do not know how to fix this error.

The error states: **Error   36 Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'long' and 'ulong'**

I understand the error has to do with the bitwise, but I'm not sure how to fix the specific situation.

```
if (!flag && (num7 < (((ulong) endLocation) - (((ulong) 4L) + num6))))
         {
           this.offsetOfFirstEntry = endLocation - ((4L + ((long) num6)) + num7);
              if (this.offsetOfFirstEntry <= 0L)
                    {
                        throw new ZipException("Invalid embedded zip archive");
                    }
}
```

**Here is a snapshot of the error:**

[image]

What is the best way to fix this type of error?

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11086333/465053).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about casting `num7` to a `ulong`?

```
if (!flag && ((ulong)num7 < (((ulong) endLocation) - (((ulong) 4L) + num6))))
```

This has nothing to do with bitwise operators, by the way.

Comment: Just noticed that, it doesn't have anything to do with bitwise, it's early brain must not be awake yet. This works great, thanks.