# c# dynamic compare exception

Tags: c#, dynamic

I can compare **long** with **int** using **dynamic**.
But I can't compare **ulong** with **int** using **dynamic**.

C# dynamic bug?

No Exception Sample

```
long a = 10000;
int b = 10;

dynamic c = a;
dynamic d = b;

if (c <= d)
    MessageBox.Show("c");
else
    MessageBox.Show("d");
```

Exception Sample

```
ulong a = 10000;
int b = 10;

dynamic c = a;
dynamic d = b;

if (c <= d) <-Exception
    MessageBox.Show("c");
else
    MessageBox.Show("d");
```

Comment: If the answer sufficiently addressed your question, you may want to accept it as the answer. You can read about how to do that [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also cannot compare `ulong` with `int` without dynamics either. This is true because `ulong` doesn't have an implicit conversion to other integral types.

If you tried, you would get this compile time error:

```
Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ulong' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug in C# dynamic. It's how the language is designed. Refer [Operator “>” cannot be applied to type 'ulong' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086333/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-type-ulong-and-int) for more information