# operator '+' is ambiguous on operands of type 'ulong' and 'int'(C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to add a ulong(Uint64) to a normal int value
,it gives me the error in the title (I'm using visual studio 2015 community)
I have also tried casting all of it into ulong but it still doesn't work
here is some example code

```
ulong balance = 0;
int salary = 5;
private void button_click()
{
     //this is what the error refrences:
     balance = balance + salary;
     //here's when I try to cast(gives the same error):
     balance = (ulong)(balance + salary);
     console.writeline("your balance is now : " + balance.tostring());
}
```

whichever the operator is  (/,+,*,-) it still gives the same error :/
I have searched all over the place and can't find anything that solves this
I have checked over 7 pages on msdn and no, Nothing :(

I just want to know how to add , subtract ,divide or multiply them , and thank you :)

Comment: its only a convertion of datatype error similar appears when you add float to int etc

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using `ulong` instead of simply `long`?  And if it's to guarantee a positive value, then why not use `ulong` and `uint` instead of mixing signed and unsigned?  And one more thing, `int.MaxValue` is pretty big, like really really big.  Do you really expect `balance` to have a bigger number than `int.MaxValue`?

Comment: @sstan yep , it's kind of like these clicker games where you mess with more than 15 quintillion at a time :D ,So yeah I'm not just using it for that "I just want the biggest value because I don't know what migh happen if it overflows" :3

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11086333/465053).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you have casted the outcome of `balance + salary` instead of casting `salary` to `ulong` to match `balance` type.

This should suffice:

```
balance += (ulong)salary;
```

If you want to use up less memory, you can cast `salary` to `uint` instead of `ulong` (32-bit integer vs 64-bit integer). Of course it does make sense in some really rare scenario (large amount of data and not so much memory).
Also you need to take in account that casting signed integer to unsigned one can result in some (un)expected behaviour.

Comment: Great Idea of casting it into uint instead! Thank you :D

Answer (score 4):

You could cast `int` to `ulong` while adding:

```
balance += (ulong)salary;
```

Or in the long form:

```
balance = balance + (ulong)salary;
```

Comment: @GamerGamesGames _"it uses more memory to convert"_. More than what?

Comment: @Dmitry More than using a Uint value which hasn't actually come across my mind before I saw the answer :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Ulong is always positive while an int is not.
But its fine to cast salary as a uint as well and then add them.

This makes sense and gives no warnings.